# Center bootstrap button in xs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have spent literally hours on this, I cannot get this button centered when the screen width entered xs mode, it started to position itself based off of the left side. I've tried looking in the bootstrap and cant find any clear indication as to why this happens.

Here is my code, mainly the third main div block with btn-posit class inside and the media queries 461-767px. Thanks

https://codepen.io/fullmetal7777/pen/RgKagp

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-10 text-center btn-posit">
            <button class="btn btn-primary twit-btn"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"><span id="twit-Text">Tweet it</span></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-default quote-btn"><div id="whole-text">Get Quote</div></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: *"Here is my code"* - where's the code?

Comment: Cant believe i forgot to link the code lol edited. If you shorted the width, youll eventually see the buttons pop over to the left side of the screen and position themselves in relation to that side instead of centering properly like that do > 767px

Comment: is this what you're going for? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/VWbrLj

Comment: That link doesn't show any buttons. Which was also another issue I'm having. I could just do margin left and right auto, but it wont show up where i want it to because it'l be hidden behind the background, and i cant do z-index unless it has absolute/relative positioning, and if i do that i cant do margins auto. Vicious cycle this is. I was really close, it just stops working properly at the xs setting.

Comment: Ah. the buttons show at the bottom if the viewport is small. How's this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/VWbrLj

Comment: Well @michaelCoker, I am very appreciative. This is one of the few things that has stumped me that I have almost given up on in my short web dev experience lol i tried changing my original code with what you gave me and i ended up hiding the buttons, so i just decided to copy and paste. Can you tell me what you did exactly to center the buttons, aside from deleting all the btn.posit entries in the media queiries? Again, I'm really thankful that this is finally solved, it was tough for me lol

Comment: Submitted an answer, let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you close to what you want.

The issues:

1. The column with the buttons in had a class of `col-xs-10` which should be `col-xs-12` if you want the buttons to be centered.
2. The twitter button still had margin right on it for the xs size, which was pushing it to the left, preventing it from centering.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xrdPVb

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the menus centered, you don't need to use the `col-*` classes to wrap them. Remove those and apply `.text-center` (which you already have), then remove all of the media queries you were using to offset the margin and try to center that column. But then I think you have some display issues from using `transform: translateX(-1);` so I just reversed the image and removed that `transform` line. The less work the browser has to do, the better, so if you can change the image, I'd just do that.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var quotes = {
 Mario: ["So long-a-Bowser!", "Nighty nighty. Ah spaghetti. Ah, ravioli. Ahh, mama mia.", "You know what they say: all toasters toast toast."],
 Luigi: ["Let's-a go...", "Oh yeah! Who's number one now?! Luigi!", "Now, THIS is where the real action is"],
 Bowser: ["Im HUUUUGE! Even scarier up close, huh?", "GAH HA HA HA! There's no WAY you're ready for a round against ME. Keep practicing, pip-squeak!"],
 Peach: ['Oh, did I win?', "Go Peachy, Go Peachy, Go Peachy! Yay! Woohoo!"],
 Yoshi: ['Yoshi!'],
 Fox: ["This is Fox, returning to base!", "Better luck next time, Falco!"],
 Falcon: ["Falcon Kick!", 'Blue Falcon!', 'Show me your moves!'],
 Marth: ["Konkaiwa bokuno kachidane! (It's my victory this time!)", "Kyoumo ikinobiru kotoga dekita. (Even today I was able to survive.)",  
    "Bokuwa makeru wake niwa ikenainda! (There's no way I can lose!)"],
 Pit: ["Three Sacred Treasures!", "It's game over for you!", "That all you got?"],
 Link: ["....."],
 Ike: ["Great... AETHER!", "I fight for my friends.", "You'll get no sympathy from me."],
 Lucario: ["Behold, the power of Aura!", "The Aura is with me!", "Max Aura!"],
 'Wii Fit Trainer': ["High energy, move that body!", "Salute the sun!", "Work hard to tone that tummy."],
 Sheik: ['I\'ve been waiting for you, Hero of Time...', 'The flow of time is always cruel.'],
 Ganandorf: ['Hero? ...I\'ve outlived more "heroes" than you can possibly imagine.', 'Behold! The power of the Demon King!',
    'I am Ganondorf, the Demon King. Don\'t take that title lightly.'],
 Mac: ["Let 'em have it, Mac!", "Way to go, Mac! You're the champ, baby!", "Nice moves, Mac. I can barely keep my eyes on you, son."],
 Palutena: ["You shall be purified.", "No one can hide from the light.", "Celestial Fireworks!"],
 Robin: ["The key to victory lies within.", "I'm always three steps ahead.", "It seems our fates are joined."],
 Shulk: ["Now it's Shulk time!", "I can change the future!", "The future is ours to decide!"],
 Sonic: ["That was almost too easy!", "Let's do that again some time!"],
 Falco: ["Personally, I prefer the air!", "You aren't worth the trouble."],
 Wario: ["Wa-Wa-Wa!", "Time for victory parade."],
 'Toon Link': ["....."],
 Lucina: ["The future is not written!", "Time to change fate!"]
}

var nameArr = ['Mario', 'Luigi', 'Bowser', 'Peach', 'Yoshi', 'Lucina', 'bowser jr', 'Wario', 'game and watch', 'donkeyk', 'diddyk', 'Link', 'Zelda', 
      'Sheik', 'Ganandorf', 'Toon Link', 'samus', 'zero suite samus', 'Pit', 'Palutena', 'Marth', 'Ike', 'Robin', 'kirby', 'king deedeedee', 'meta knight',
      'Mac', 'placeholder', 'Fox', 'Falco', 'pikachu', 'charizard', 'Lucario', 'jigglypuff', 'Greninja', 'duck hunt', 'Rob', 'ness', 'Falcon', 'villager', 
      'olimar', 'Wii Fit Trainer', 'dr mario', 'dark pit', 'Lucina', 'Shulk', 'pacman', 'Megaman', 'Sonic'];




var imgurID = '0RQtP';
var key = "cfb3f86a62ab07c";

function randomFxn(){
 $.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/album/' + imgurID + '/images',
 headers: {'Authorization': 'Client-ID '+ key},
 }).done(function(data) {
  showZones(data)
 });
 }


var lastNum = '70';

function showZones(jsonData){
 var name = '';
 
 
 do{
 var nameNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*(Object.keys(quotes).length));
 // var nameNum = 70;
 console.log(nameNum);
 
 } while (nameNum == lastNum)
 console.log(lastNum);
 lastNum = nameNum;
 console.log(lastNum);

 name = Object.keys(quotes)[nameNum];
 
 var quoteArrLength = quotes[name].length;
 var randQuoteNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*quoteArrLength)
 var randQuote = '\"' + quotes[name][randQuoteNum] + '\"';
 var indexMult = (nameArr.indexOf(name)*8);
 var addToIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*8);
 var url = jsonData.data[(indexMult)+addToIndex].link;
 var imgCss = 'url(' + url + ')';
 var isReverse = Math.floor(Math.random()*2); 

 $('h3').text('-' + name);
 $('h2').text('Hero? ...I\'ve outlived more "heroes" than you can possibly imagine.');

 $('.bg').fadeOut(500, function() {
  if(isReverse==1){
   $(this).css({'background-image': imgCss, 'transform': 'scaleX(1)'}).fadeIn(700);
  }
  else{
   $(this).css({'background-image': imgCss, 'transform': 'scaleX(-1)'}).fadeIn(700);
  }      
 });
}

var num = 0;
$('.quote-btn').click(function(){

 if (num == 0){
  num++;

  randomFxn();

  setTimeout(function(){
   num = 0;
  }, 1200);
 }
});
});
```

```css
body, html{
 height: 100%;
}

.bg,
.quote-btn {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}

.bg{
 background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/sxwO4y3.jpg");
 height: 100%;
 background-size: 70% 100%;
}

.jumbotron{
 margin-left: 16.66666667%;
 margin-top: -78vh; 
 background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.4);
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

h2, h3{
 color: white;
 opacity: 1;
 font-weight: 900;

}

h2{
 margin-top: -3vh;
 margin-left: -1.7vw;
}

h3{
 float: right;
}

.quote-btn {
   border-color: #5e1111 #5e1111 hsl(0, 69%, 17%);
   background-image: url("http://www.wtfgamersonly.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Super-Smash-Bros.-img.2.jpg");
 background-position: 50% 60%;
 height: 45px;
 width: 140px; 
}

.twit-btn{
 height: 45px;
 width: 140px;
 margin-right: 35px;
}

#whole-text{
 font-weight: 800;
 color: #BC1818;
 font-size: 22px;
}

.btn.quote-btn:focus,
.btn.quote-btn:active:focus,
.btn.quote-btn.active:focus,
.btn.quote-btn.focus,
.btn.quote-btn:active.focus,
.btn.quote-btn.active.focus,
.btn.twit-btn:focus,
.btn.twit-btn:active:focus,
.btn.twit-btn.active:focus,
.btn.twit-btn.focus,
.btn.twit-btn:active.focus,
.btn.twit-btn.active.focus{
 outline-color: none;
 outline-style: none;
 border-color: #5e1111 #5e1111 hsl(0, 69%, 17%);
}

.btn.quote-btn:hover{
 border-style: none;
}

.btn.quote-btn:active{
 background-image: url("http://www.wtfgamersonly.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Super-Smash-Bros.-img.2.jpg");
 opacity: .8;
}




@media only screen and (max-height: 568px){
 .jumbotron{
  margin-top:-89vh;
 }
}

@media only screen and (min-height: 569px){
 .jumbotron{
  margin-top:-80vh;
 }

 .btn-posit {
  margin-top: -42vh;
 }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 1199px){
 .bg{
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
 }
}

/*medium*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) { 
 .jumbotron{
  margin-left: 8.33333333%;
 }

}

/*small*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px){
 .jumbotron{
  margin-left: 4.15%;
 }

}

/*xs*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 461px) and (max-width: 767px){
 .jumbotron{
  margin-left: 8.33333333%;
 }

 .btn-posit{
  width: auto;
 }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 460px) {
 h2{
  font-size: 22px;
 }

 h3{
  font-size: 18px;
 }

 .btn-posit{
  /*padding-left: 78px; */
  margin-left: 1%;
 }

 .jumbotron{
  margin-left: 8%;
 }

 .twit-btn{
  margin-right: 55px;
  width: auto;
 }

 #twit-text{
  display: none;
 }
}

/*@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 422px) {
 h2{
  font-size: 22px;
 }

 h3{
  font-size: 18px;
 }

 .twit-btn{
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
 }

 .btn-posit{
  padding-left: 15%;
 }

 #twit-text{
  display: none;
 }
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/5ad62430a6.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>AwesomeDesigns Random Quote Generator</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 </head> 
<body>
 <div class="bg"></div>
 
 <div class="container"> 
  <div class="row"> 
   <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 col-sm-11 col-xs-10 jumbotron"> 
    <h2>"Andrews Random Quote Generator. "</h2>
    <h3>-Andrew Hickman</h3>
   </div>  
  </div>
  
 </div>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="text-center btn-posit">
    <button class="btn btn-primary twit-btn"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"><span id="twit-Text">Tweet it</span></i></button>
    <button class="btn btn-default quote-btn"><div id="whole-text">Get Quote</div></button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</html>
```

Comment: For some reason, the buttons end up fading out and hiding when i hit them. Its like their taking on the properties of the .bg css change and then hiding behind it? This is the only js property that actually changes stuff.

Comment: $('.bg').fadeOut(500, function() {
          if(isReverse==1){
       $(this).css({'background-image': imgCss, 'transform': 
    'scaleX(1)'}).fadeIn(700);
      }
  else{
   $(this).css({'background-image': imgCss, 'transform': 'scaleX(-1)'}).fadeIn(700);
  }      
 }); I cant get it formatted properly, no clue why, i indented with 4 spaces.

Comment: @Fullmetal7777 if you can't figure it out, you should post a new question.

Comment: @Fullmetal7777 np. That's just unrelated to the original question and likely a more complex fix than the original question, too. Also be sure to choose which answer you think is the best solution if the problem in the question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

adding text-center class seemed to be the fix!